# Get dimensions of referenced image (Magic Fields fields plugin with phpThumb)

Tags: plugin-magic-fields

I'm displaying a group of thumbnails on a Wordpress site using the [Magic Fields plugin](http://wiki.magicfields.org/doku.php?id=magic_fields_v20)

Here's the code in my template:

```
  <?php
  $client_images = get_group ('images');
  foreach($client_images as $image){ ?>
  <div class="thumb">
      <a href="<?php echo $image['client_image'][2]['original']; ?>">
        <?php echo "<img src='".$image['client_image'][3]['thumb']."' />" ;?>
      </a>
     <div class="tooltip">
      <h5>Resolution</h5>
      <p>[ORIGINAL RESOLUTION]</p>
      <h5>Credit</h5>
      <p><?php echo $image['client_image_credit'][4]; ?></p>
      <h5>Description</h5>
      <p><?php echo $image['client_image_description'][5]; ?></p>
    </div>
  </div>
    <?php }
  ?>
```

Where it says [ORIGINAL RESOLUTION], I'd like to print the resolution (e.g. "1200x800") of the source image.

Magic Fields uses [phpThumb](https://github.com/magic-fields-team/Magic-Fields-2/blob/master/thirdparty/phpthumb/phpThumb.php) to generate thumbnails. phpThumb seems to have a function for this purpose:

```
//Getting the original size of the image
if( preg_match('/'.MF_FILES_NAME.'/',$image_name_clean) ){
  $image_name_clean = preg_replace('/'.MF_FILES_NAME.'\//','',$image_name_clean);
  $file = MF_FILES_DIR.$image_name_clean;
}else{
  $file = WP_CONTENT_DIR.DS.$image_name_clean;
}

if(file_exists($file) && (empty($_GET['w']) || empty($_GET['h']))){
    $size = @getimagesize($file);
    $default['w'] = $size[0];
    $default['h'] = $size[1];
}
```

Would anyone be able to help me connect the dots? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have worked many times with timthumb, but I do not know magic fields, and I am sorry, but i fail to understand a few things :

1. you want to put a FULL resolution inside a tooltip ?
2. does thispart of your code `$image['client_image'][2]['original'];` from above works ?
3. if it does, there is no reason it should not work in the other div .

anyhow , you can pass parameters to timthumb directly for example like so :

define the variable with a URL

```
$thumb_for_tim = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'single-post-thumbnail' ) ; // or in your case - your custom field value - if it returns a URL
```

and then call it

```
<img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/scripts/timthumb.php?src=<?php echo $thumb_for_tim; ?>&amp;h=155&amp;w=180&amp;zc=1&amp;f=2" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" h & w are the height and width ..
```

**EDIT** ok, after your comment it is more clear . at first when you wrote "[ORIGINAL RESOLUTION]" I thought you wanted the image itself.
in that case the answer is much simpler . PHP has a special function for that .

[getimagesize()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php)

```
$size = getimagesize($filename);
```

so just point the URL of the image to $filename;

FYI - wordpress itself has a function to get imagesize , it is called

```
wp_get_attachment_image_src
```

use like so :

```
$image_attributes = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment->ID,full );
```

it will returns an array

- [0] => url
- [1](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php) => width
- [2] => height

  so `echo  $image_attributes[1];` will give you width, and `$image_attributes[2]` will give you height...

Comment: I'm not trying to display the image inside the tooltip, but rather the _dimensions_ of the image. The thumbnail links to the full sized image, and the tooltip tells the user what the resolution of that image is, e.g., "1200px x 800px"

Comment: see my modified answer .